# is there any mantra equal to whole Lalita sahasranama?

Tags: sri-vidya

Since "Rama" is equal to the whole Vishnu Sahasranama, is there any mantra/word/name which is equal to the whole Lalita Sahasranamam?

Comment: Are you asking one mantra, nama of devi equal to Lalita Sahasranama?

Comment: One mantra or nama...  doesn't matter if it's Devi's or any other..